# Need to try and count repeated lists within a list

Tags: python

Im trying to count how many repeated lists there are inside a list. But it doesnt work the same way I could count repeated elements in just a list. Im fairly new to python, so apologies if it sounds too easy.

this is what i did

```
x=  [["coffee", "cola", "juice" "tea" ],["coffee", "cola", "juice" "tea"]
["cola", "coffee", "juice" "tea" ]]
dictt= {}

for item in x:

    dictt[item]= dictt.get(item, 0) +1

return(dictt)
```

Comment: what are you using the dict for?

Comment: Could you explain to us, what you are trying to achieve? Maybe some example input _and_ example result?

Comment: Read this http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries - lists can't be used as keys - you can modify to use other type of keys like tuples

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka: You meant lists _cannot_ be used as keys in dictionaries, because they are not hashable (while tuples are hashable).

Comment: @Tadeck sure))) thank you) just mistype

Answer (score 2):

Your code ***almost*** works. As others have mentioned, lists cannot be 
used as dictionary keys but tuples can.
The solution is to turn each list into a tuple.

```
>>> x=  [["coffee", "cola", "juice", "tea"], ### <-- this list appears twice
...      ["coffee", "cola", "juice", "tea"],
...      ["cola", "coffee", "juice", "tea"]] ### <-- this list appears once
>>> 
>>> dictt= {}
>>> 
>>> for item in x:
...     # turn the list into a tuple
...     key = tuple(item)
...
...     # use the tuple as the dictionary key
...     # get the current count for this key or 0 if the key does not yet exist
...     # then increment the count
...     dictt[key]= dictt.get(key, 0) + 1
... 
>>> dictt
{('cola', 'coffee', 'juice', 'tea'): 1, ('coffee', 'cola', 'juice', 'tea'): 2}
>>>
```

You can turn the tuples back into lists if you need to.

```
>>> for key in dictt:
...     print list(key), 'appears ', dictt[key], 'times'
... 
['cola', 'coffee', 'juice', 'tea'] appears  1 times
['coffee', 'cola', 'juice', 'tea'] appears  2 times
>>>
```

In addition, Python has a collections.Counter() class which is designed specifically for counting things. (NOTE: You will still need to turn the lists into tuples.)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for item in x:
...    counter[tuple(item)] += 1
... 
>>> counter
Counter({('coffee', 'cola', 'juice', 'tea'): 2, ('cola', 'coffee', 'juice', 'tea'): 1})
>>>
```

Counter() is a subclass of dict(), so all the dictionary methods still work.

```
>>> counter.keys()
[('coffee', 'cola', 'juice', 'tea'), ('cola', 'coffee', 'juice', 'tea')]
>>> k = counter.keys()[0]
>>> k
('coffee', 'cola', 'juice', 'tea')
>>> counter[k]
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dictt = {}
>>> for i in x:
    dictt[str(set(i))] = dictt.get(str(set(i)),0) + 1


>>> dictt
{"set(['coffee', 'juicetea', 'cola'])": 3}
```

This is not the best , but works .
because list is not hashable , so I supply a string as key.